# CSS/HTML layout Broken. It looks like margin-left but there is not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

I have 3 blocks which there is 
Block 1 - div 40% width
Block 2 - div 30% width
Block 3 - div 30% width

It is using bootstrap.
Pressing F5 It loads fine. But then It breaks the layout.

I think it can be some problem with CSS or even PHP some hidden bug.

The `<section class="col-2 product-photo">` should have no margin from it parent. And it has not. But It is loading like has margin-left from parent.

Does someone know what is the problem?

Comment: Hi Andrea, this margin is ok. The problem is there is 3 columns with float left, but It is broken. The problem is horizontal

Comment: Please don't include links to live code in your questions. When you fix the live code, your question will no longer contain an example of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: go to where global.css is and change line 92 to this  **.limit-big {
        width: 100%;
        }** in your page add a class container like this  **<div class="wrapper limit-big center" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="container">
    <!-- your content -->
    </div>
    </div>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css  to fix

```
.limit-big.center {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks allen! It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some white-spaces in there. You can fix the problem by using this, on the parent div (.wrapper.limit-big):

```
font-size: 0;
```

It works for me on Firefox + Chrome
But next, you'll have to fix each font-size for children content.